# bind function parameters to thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, boost

I tried calling a function with parameters, using boost, but it does not work. the code is this

```
void Simulate::cr_number_threaded(lint nodes) {
    for(lint i = 0; i < trials_per_thread; i++) {
        // code
    }

}

void Simulate::run_cr_number() {
    vec_cr_number.clear();
    boost::thread t[threads];

    for(int i = 0; i < n_s.size(); i++) {
        // n_s[i] is the current number of nodes
        for(int t_idx = 0; t_idx < threads; t_idx++)
            t[t_idx] = boost::thread(cr_number_threaded, n_s[i]);
        // etc...
    }


}
```

the error I get is the following:

> Simulate.cpp: In member function 'void
>   Simulate::run_cr_number()':
>   Simulate.cpp:27: error: no matching
>   function for call to
>   'boost::thread::thread(, long int&)'

UPDATE:
I followed the suggestions. Using the first solution I get

> Simulate.cpp: In member function 'void
>   Simulate::run_cr_number()':
>   Simulate.cpp:28: error: no matching
>   function for call to 'bind(, long int&)'
>   ../../boost_1_44_0/boost/bind/bind.hpp:1472:
>   note: candidates are:
>   boost::_bi::bind_t::type>
>   boost::bind(F, A1) [with F = void
>   (Simulate::*)(lint), A1 = long int]
>   ../../boost_1_44_0/boost/bind/bind.hpp:1728:
>   note:
>   boost::_bi::bind_t::type, boost::_mfi::dm,
>   typename
>   boost::_bi::list_av_1::type>
>   boost::bind(M T::*, A1) [with A1 =
>   long int, M = void ()(lint), T =
>   Simulate]

using the second one I get this instead

> Simulate.cpp: In member function 'void
>   Simulate::run_cr_number()':
>   Simulate.cpp:28: error: no matching
>   function for call to
>   'boost::thread::swap(boost::_bi::bind_t,
>   boost::_bi::list2,
>   boost::_bi::value > >)'
>   ../../boost_1_44_0/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:310: note: candidates are: void
>   boost::thread::swap(boost::thread&)

Answer (score 1):

1) boost::thread is not `copyable` but `swappable`

2) you need to specify member function and pass an instance

something like this:

```
t[t_idx].swap(boost::thread(&Simulate::cr_number_threaded, this, n_s[i]));
```

in this case you need to be sure that `this` will live longer than threads.

Comment: `cr_number_threaded` is a member function so you need to pass an instance and fully qualify it's name: `boost::bind( &Simulate::cr_number_threaded, this, n_s[i] )`.

Comment: I do not get compilation errors using this: t[t_idx] = boost::thread(&Simulate::cr_number_threaded, this, n_s[i]);

Comment: @Banana: it's using this constructor http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.multiple_argument_constructor that does the `bind` for you.

Comment: @Banana: corrected, boost thread recently added this facility